# scrollview, multiple buttons but no autoresize portrait/landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have setup with help of a friend, a scrollview, a loop to add 25 buttons on 4 pages for a max of 100 buttons (which are really just images or thumbnails for a photo thumbnail slider).

There are 5 across and 5 down; however, it is programmed for landscape and do not know the proper code to correct this for automatically sizing the buttons/thumbnails into smaller ones or shrink for a portrait view.

Since I cannot change the buttons across and down (like 4 across and 6 down), I presume I will just change the button size to shrink it, but I don't know how that is done.

I've declared the UIScrollView *scrollView and ints in ViewController.h

```
    int buttonNumber;
    int maxButtonNumber;
    int Pages;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    NSString *detailImageString;

    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *topBar;
    IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *buttons;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton*thumbIcon;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *thumbIconImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *topBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

Here is the ViewController.m

```
    scrollView.bounces=NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;

    buttons=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    static const CGFloat ButtonWidth = 145;
    static const CGFloat ButtonHeight = 85;

   scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    buttonNumber = 0;
    maxButtonNumber=100;

            Pages=4; 


    for (int i = 0; i < Pages; i++) {
        UIView *pageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        pageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


        int x = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            if (buttonNumber > maxButtonNumber) {
                break;
            }
            buttonNumber++;
            //Create 5 Rows
            int row = j / 5;
            if (j % 5 == 0) {
                x = 0;
            }
            thumbIcon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            thumbIcon.tag = buttonNumber;
            [thumbIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(x * (ButtonWidth + 30) + 90, row * (ButtonHeight + 20) + 75, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight)];

            thumbIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d.jpg", buttonNumber]]; 

            [thumbIcon setImage:thumbIconImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [pageView addSubview:thumbIcon];
            [thumbIcon setEnabled:YES];
            [buttons addObject:thumbIcon];
            x++;
        }

       [pageView setFrame:CGRectMake(i * 1024, 0, 1024, 704)];

       [scrollView addSubview:pageView];

         [pageView release];

    }
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024 * Pages, 704)];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have any UIView (including UIButtons) autoresize by using `@property(nonatomic) UIViewAutoresizing autoresizingMask` of `UIView`.  For example, if you would like the width of your UIButton to change during rotation you could do something like the following right after you initialize your buttons:

```
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Check out the documentation on autoresizingMask and see if it does what you'd like: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6

Comment: It's a good tool and I will experiment with it to gain knowledge. But it didn't resolve the issue. Because I am creating an array for the button buttons=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];, then creating a loop for those buttons for 4 pages in a UIScrollView, I can't seem to work with the rotation properly